# how to add content inside a <div> tag that is empty using js

Tags: javascript, html

how do I add content inside a `<div>` tag that is empty using `js` ?

```
<div class="price"></div>
```

when it's empty I want it to display this

```
<div class="price">"By Enquiry Only"</div>
```

I tried this but it wouldn't work

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ($(this).find('.price').is(':empty'))
    document.getElementByClass("demo").innerHTML="By Enquiry Only";
</script>
```

Comment: The expression `$(this).find('.price').is(':empty')` indicates you're using jQuery. Tag your question with the `jquery` tag if it is relevant. You can click "edit" underneath the tags of your question to add it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with css:

```
.price:empty:after
{
    content: "By Enquiry Only";
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbhyA/)

**Note:**

do: `document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0]`

Instead of: `document.getElementByClass("demo")`

Or just: `$(".demo").html("By Enquiry Only");`

Comment: It seems that (at least in Chrome) the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class will fail to select an element if it has whitespace in it (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbhyA/1/)). Also, this feature is not supported in IE <9, if older browsers are a concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 if ( !$(document).find('.price').html().length )
  $(".demo").html("By Enquiry Only");
</script>
```

Also keep in mind that this will find the first element with the price class. If you want to do that for each of them, use the jQuery `each()` method applied to your class

Comment: Note that this will skip `.price` elements with just whitespace text content. If those should be included, then the `if` condition will need to use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/): `!$.trim($(document).find('.price').html()).length`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the element by the wrong class name. You should also call `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClass`, it's plural and has `Name` at the end.

```
document.getElementsByClass("demo"); //demo is wrong class name
```

It should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName("price")[0]
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  if ($('.price').length > 0){
     if($('.price').text() == '')
        $('.demo').html('By Enquiry Only');
  }
});
</script>
```